# Validate Maven values in Java

Tags: java, validation, maven

This might be an easy task so I believe there should be something out there already. I'm trying to validate Maven related stuff like: artifact ID, group ID, Java package name, Version and a path.

Those are going to be provided from a NetBeans plug in in order to generate a maven project, thus need to be verified from the plugin before even attempting to create the project. (More friendly than letting the process blow up).

Right now I'm trying to verify with Java string checks but there should be something better like a regex.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do mean exactly by 'validate' ?  Fail the build if some validation fails?

Comment: Where are you validating these values in Java and why? Also, aren't you parsing the POM using some XML library? If so, how do Java String checks and regexs fit into the picture. I'm afraid I simply cannot understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I built a NetBeans plugin to generate a Maven project (Atlassian Plugins). Those values are parameters and need to be valid.

Comment: That is not at all what this sounded like to me.  You might want to give more detail in your question.

Comment: Have you consider using a Maven Archetype?  Would that help any?

Comment: The thing is that using an archetype on it's own doesn't do the trick. Basically Atlassian provides a "JDK" for their plugins with some scripts that do all the dirty trick. I did try the archetype approach but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maven's [Model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html) class and validate with their [ModelValidator](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/validation/ModelValidator.html).

Comment: This did the trick. I'm getting the errors, just need to filter them for the ones I'm looking for. Thanks!